# How to change the background-color of checkbox field in sencha touch on checked event using only CSS

Tags: css, sencha-touch-2.3

I have this code that changes the styling of the checkbox "tick" mark on selecting the checkbox,

```
.x-input-checkbox:checked  + .x-field-mask:after {
//Your style here
}
```

P.S. The above code is only for the check mark not the whole field.

but I dont know how to change the background color of the checkbox field on selecting it using purely CSS (the whole field)

Answer (score 0):

You have to manipulate the `.x-field-mask` class. `.x-field-mask:after` is only used to draw the tick.

```
.x-field-mask {
  background-color: green;
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I have already tried this, .x-field-mask takes care of only the background of the tick mark. Not the whole field. But appreciate the try.

Comment: That's interesting. It worked for me. What browser are you testing on? You might try to clear the cache.

Comment: I use cognito mode. but still  I did clear it. and I use 10 different machines parellelly for one single visual design so its not possible that I am having a cache issue. I use chrome, IE, safari